# Trouble with data loading to H2O on R in Windows

Tags: r, h2o, rtvs

I have problems with data loading to H2O in R on Windows. When I run basic commands such as h2o.clusterInfo or as.h2o(localH2O, dat, key = 'dat'), I got an error message - ***Error in .... : unused argument (...).*** Like on screen. I use RTVS na Microsoft R Open 3.2.5

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that code no longer works is that it's syntax from the H2O 2.0 API, which has been retired for about a year or longer.  Since H2O 3.0, `h2o.clusterInfo()` no longer has arguments and `as.h2o()` no longer has the `key` argument.  Check out the documentation for these functions inside your H2O R package, or [here](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/h2o/versions/3.8.3.3/topics/h2o.clusterInfo) and [here](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/h2o/versions/3.8.3.3/topics/as.h2o).

Comment: Thank you very much!
If I use this commands _h2o.clusterInfo()_ and _dath2o <- as.h2o(dat, destination_frame = "dat")_  it works!